# Изучение простых табличных подзапросов с использованием операций IN, ALL, ANY

Tags: sql-server

1. Вывести список студентов, которые не состоят ни в
   одном из клубов.
2. Вывести названия клубов, год основания которых
   больше, чем год основания остальных клубов.
3. Вывести названия клубов, год основания которых
   превышает год основания хотя бы одного из клубов.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если ожидается, что кто-то выполнит задание, то это не по адресу.

Comment: Домашние задания нужно выполнять самостоятельно, вам не стыдно, Владимир?

Comment: Есть хотя бы попытки написать запрос?

Comment: некоторые наводки, все ровно этот вопрос закроют ) 1. left, where [field] is null
2. where [field]> all(select
3. where [field]> any(select